# 17.10 DNS Requires root.servers response

Tags: dns

I''m currently on 17.10 and having DNS issues.

I have my network configured to use an internal DNS server 192.168.1.50 and my firewall set to only allow DNS from the DNS server and not from any clients.

Ubuntu constantly tries to query root-servers.net and refuses to allow Internet access if it can't reach or get a response from root-servers e.g. a.root-servers.net. If I configure a firewall rule to allow my Ubuntu system to perform DNS queries everything is fine.

Is this behavior by design?

Comment: I think I've solved it. Problem appears to be systemd-resovled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved it. Problem appears to be systemd-resovled.

Found this set of instructions on another post (credit to poster in that forum - lost the link).

$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service

$ sudo service systemd-resolved stop

Put the following line in the [main] section of your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

dns=default

Delete the symlink /etc/resolv.conf

$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf

Restart network-manager

$ sudo service network-manager restart

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
The format is simple:

```
nameserver n.s.i.p
```

Comment: Why does Ubuntu constantly query root-servers.net and not allow DNS resolution if there's no response?

Comment: because there dns server is running , try to disable it if you don't need it